# XBMC doesn’t downmix sound from 5.1 to stereo

Tags: sound, xbmc

I have installed XBMC (team-xbmc PPA) on my laptop (Kubuntu 10.10) and the sound from 5.1 movies isn’t downmixed correctly to stereo, even though the option is enabled. I have already tried http://forum.xbmc.org/showpost.php?p=587582&postcount=286 and it didn’t change a thing. Other players (VLC…) can do this correctly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Ah, the two links from that forum post make poor assumptions about your audio hardware, e.g., not all HDMI devices are exposed in that fashion according to that card/device/subdevice scheme.  Please see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/AlsaInfo.

Comment: @fliegenderfrosch - if you no longer have an issue and you cannot provide an answer to how you resolved it, then you should probably delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember, there was a bug, with some AC3 5.1 encoded videos.  If the stereo setting works OK for 7.1 videos, or other , then this is it. Nothing more to do that trying a daily build with the bug fixed, or older version without the bug

Comment: I don’t think the problem still exists for me. Thanks for your answer anyway!